# ¿Dar como respuesta a una pregunta un enlace a SO Ingles es válido?

Tags: discusión

Soy novato en android, pero suelo ver las preguntas e intento resolverlas.

He visto una pregunta de un tema que desconozco en Android pero buscando, he dado con la solución en SO en Ingles.

Mi intención era la de copiar el enlace al post original y ponerlo como comentario, pero claro para escribir ahí debes tener mas de 50 puntos.

¿Lo correcto que sería?

1 - ¿Poner el enlace como una respuesta sería adecuado? En principio no lo he hecho por estar la respuesta en inglés.

2 - ¿Hacer una traducción mala de un tema que no conozco? Tampoco lo veo.

3 - ¿Abrir Android Studio recrear el entorno del usuario y probar yo mismo la solución para después venir aquí a dar una respuesta? Lo correcto, pero a lo mejor tardo demasiado.

4 - ¿Hacer como que no he visto nada y seguir a lo mio?  :)

Un saludo!

Comment: Ahora ya podés hacer comentarios... que espero que sean interesantes!! `:-)`

Comment: ¡¡ Gracias @Mariano !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El sitio en inglés tiene una gran cantidad de respuestas y preguntas y la probabilidad de que se encuentre una respuesta ahí es alta. Por lo tal, intentemos los siguientes pasos para contestar una pregunta *aquí* que tenga una solución *allá*.

No todas las preguntas son iguales. Investiguemos si hay alguna diferencia sutil que se este escondiendo.  Tal vez esta marque la diferencia en como contestaremos a la pregunta.  Si la pregunta es similar, entonces la respuesta puede ser similar.  No hay problema en traducir las respuestas de inglés a español siempre y cuando anotes el enlace de donde venga la respuesta traducida.  Así, veremos que la respuesta esta basada en otra ya publicada en el sitio en inglés. Por ejemplo, cuando escribí [este post para el blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/una-receta-para-promover-nuestra-comunidad/), indique al final que estaba basado en un post en el blog en inglés.  No fue una publicación copiada letra por letra. Aunque que la mayoría si fue traducida, se introdujo otras ideas y cambios a la publicación original.  Hagamos lo mismo con preguntas traducidas.

Si hay oportunidad de verificar los resultados, hagámoslo por favor. La idea aquí es de contribuir buenas respuestas originales pero ocurrirán oportunidades como la que mencionas tu donde la respuesta ya fue compartida.  En esos casos, sigamos los pasos sugeridos anteriormente.

El problema con dejar un enlace a las respuestas que se encuentran en el sitio en inglés es que no se gana nada.  El usuario tendrá que visitar al otro sitio y si no tiene la habilidad de leer y comprender el inglés bien, lo frustraremos.  Por eso, es importante el traducir y publicar aquí.

Answer (score 2):

Agregando a la respuesta de [Juan M ♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m), que ya es una eminencia en lo que respecta a la relación SOes ↭ SO, quería poner énfasis en algo:

Poner un enlace como una respuesta no es adecuado, no importa si está en español, inglés, ruso, suajili o jeringoso. Primero porque el link podría romperse en el futuro pero, más importante, porque todos queremos ver las respuestas acá.

Por supuesto no es necesario poner todo lo que esté en ese link... Pero al menos una descripción breve de cómo solucionarlo.

---

<sup>Comentario aparte: todos sabemos que es muy molesto ser un usuario nuevo, querer comentar y no poder hacerlo. -Es malísimo! Pero fue una decisión basada en la experiencia de SE: [las desventajas de permitir que todos comenten tienen muchísimo más peso que los pocos comentarios no hechos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/304899).</sup>

Lamentablemente no te queda otra opción más que aguantarte hasta tener 50 puntos.